# SELECT columns different from GROUP BY columns

Tags: mysql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

Having this database schema (just for illustration purpose)

```
[articles (id_article, title)] 
[articles_tags (id_tag, id_article)]
[tags (id_tag, name)]
```

using MySQL it's possible to do:

```
SELECT a.title, COUNT(at.id_tag) tag_count FROM articles a
JOIN articles_tags at ON a.id_article = at.id_article
JOIN tags t ON t.id_tag = at.id_tag
GROUP BY a.id_article
ORDER BY tag_count DESC
```

resulting in a result where you have on each row article's title and article's tag count, e.g.

```
mysql for beginner | 8
ajax for dummies   | 4
```

Since ORACLE doesn't support non-aggregated columns in SELECT statement, is it possible to do this anyhow in one query? When you fulfill ORACLE's needs by either adding aggregate function to SELECT statement or adding the column to GROUP BY statement you already get different results.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  Return `id_article` in the SELECT list, instead of `title`, and wrap that whole query in parens to make it an inline view, and then select from that, and a join to the `articles` table to get the associated `title`.

For example:

```
SELECT b.title
     , c.tag_count
  FROM ( SELECT a.id_article
              , COUNT(at.id_tag) tag_count 
           FROM articles a
           JOIN articles_tags at ON a.id_article = at.id_article
           JOIN tags t ON t.id_tag = at.id_tag
          GROUP BY a.id_article
       ) c
  JOIN articles b
    ON b.id_article = c.id_article
 ORDER BY c.tag_count DESC
```

---

You can also evaluate whether you really need the `articles` table included in the inline view. We could do a `GROUP BY at.id_article` instead.

I think this returns an equivalent result:

```
SELECT b.title
     , c.tag_count
  FROM ( SELECT at.id_article
              , COUNT(at.id_tag) tag_count 
           FROM articles_tags at
           JOIN tags t ON t.id_tag = at.id_tag
          GROUP BY at.id_article
       ) c
  JOIN articles b
    ON b.id_article = c.id_article
 ORDER BY c.tag_count DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, good enough for me. I guess we can't talk about a solution without a subquery. But as I see this subquery runs only once, so it's very effective. Well done.

Comment: Well, Oracle doesn't necessarily materialize that inline view as a "derived table" like MySQL does. (That's an option Oracle can do, but I think the Oracle optimizer may be able to re-write that.)

Comment: A simpler solution might just be to wrap a **`MAX()`** aggregate function around `a.title` in your original query. If `a.title` is dependent on `a.id_article`, it should be an equivalent result. (I think you asked how to do it *without* adding an aggregate.)

Comment: I did - that is an interesting proposal indeed. I'll however stick with your second query since it seems more 'clean' to me.